# The laptop adapter works only after heating it up

Tags: laptop, power, adapter

I have Dell Latitude C640.  Its adapter works only when heated.

The LED light turns ON only when it gets extremely heated.  I use to heat it on the electric heater.

Can anyone tell me the solution?

Comment: I do NOT mean this in a snarky way I swear: Get a new power adapter. It sounds like there's a loose connection - warming it up causes just enough expansion to make the connection solid. Replace it as soon as you can.

Comment: The words "fire hazard" come to mind.  Replace it.

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to by a new one, 9/10 the heat causes loose contacts to get connected. Anyway your adapter is broken, I don't really think you want a short on it when attached to your laptop, so replace it.